# Бездействие в асинхронном коде в python

Tags: python, asyncio, event-loop

Как можно замерить сколько мы ничего не делали в асинхронном коде? Код создает кучу task и через asyncio.gather вызывает их. И выполняется gather например X секунд, как узнать сколько времени из этого X мы ничего не делали? Замерять время от await до await не получится так как task`и внутри вызывают сложный асинхронный код. Может кто-то уже разбирался с этим и может помочь?

Думал поменять политику event loop, но кажется это вообще не о том.

Comment: Ничего не делали - это что имеется в виду? Ожидание ответа от сервера считается ничего не деланием?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[time.process_time()](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/time.html#time.process_time) показывает время которое процесс исполнялся. При использовании 100% процессора в течении минуты покажет 60 сек, при нагрузке 5% - покажет 3 сек. Время за исключением времени сна.